Error with sudo add-apt-repository retrieving gpg key timed out
I'm trying to add this repository:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yubico/stable

on an Ubuntu Server 24.04.6 LTS. When I run the above command, it prompts me for sudo; I enter the password, and it stays idle for a few minutes. Then, it displays:
PPA for stable Yubico software.
More info: https://launchpad.net/~yubico/+archive/ubuntu/stable
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

When I press Enter, after a few seconds, it shows:
Error: retrieving gpg key timed out.

I tested this repository installation on my Linux Mint, and it worked. Can anyone help me with this problem?
